# Formulating an arrangement problem with STRIPS

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, search-algorithms, planning

The problem is rearranging furniture in a flat.
We are given rectangular rooms of natural width and height with doors between them, (the walls have no width)
and rectangular furniture at starting positions and goal positions.
The operations are moving each piece of furniture one block each direction (up,down,right, left), and rotating it 90 degrees at each direction.

Information about the STRIPS language:
1. The state of the world consists of first order ground atoms: Only positive predicates on ground objects.
2. Operations consist of: a list of bound variables, and the following sets: preconditions (with positive or negative atoms) and effects (with positive or negative atoms) with no free variables.
3. An operation can to be turned into an action using substitution of all variables of the operation, resulting in preconditions and effects with positive or negative **ground** atoms
4. A relevant operation is one that given the current goal state, can be turned into an action such that the effects hold in the state.

How can I formulate preconditions to these operations?
What I came up with up until now is that I need to represent each 1x1 square as an object in the propositions.

The main thing I don't understand how to model is that each operation's precondition needs to depend on the furniture size - the amount and position of blocks that need to be clear to move a piece of furniture depends on it's dimentions.

Rotating would be even more complex; some of the new positions of the piece of furniture would need to be checked to be empty (what is currently not taken by the piece of furniture) and some would not (what is currently taken by the piece of furniture).

How is it possible to model it into the form of STRIPS?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is a nice practice exercise for learning preconditions.  We're not here to solve your exercise for you, but if you can frame a more specific question we might be able to help you.  Why don't you show us what you tried?  What difficulty specifically are you having dealing with the furniture size?  That'll be just one more constant/parameter that appears in the formula you write.  What's the issue?  Rotation is merely a matter of geometry -- try drawing a picture, and write it out.  You'll need to make some effort on your own.

Comment: @D.W. The problem I'm having is that if the furniture width is for example 7, there would need to be 7 preconditions for moving up, if it was 10, there would need to be 10. Is it even possible to model with STRIPS?

Comment: NightRa, there's no need for 7 preconditions; use a quantifier.  I have no idea what STRIPS is (but beware that syntax for tools or programming languages are generally off-topic for this site).

Comment: @D.W. STRIPS requires first order ground atoms as the logical expressions => Can't use quentifiers. STRIPS isn't a tool, but the language in which a planning problem is expressed, and the algorithm needs to work on the structure of the language.

Comment: That information helps clarify what you're asking.  I suggest you edit the question to include all of it in the question itself (comments exist only to help you improve the question, and might disappear at any time).

Comment: Hint: try coming up with a higher-level predicate or set of predicates that abstract away from positional information. More specifically, the predicate(s) should form natural equivalence classes that give you the distinctions you want.

Comment: @ShyPerson Can you explain what you mean in your second sentence? What do you mean by "natural equivalence classes" and distinctions between what?

Comment: If I have higher-level predicates, I'm unsure if it's then possible to generate them on the effects list.

Comment: Okay, so you have a object for each location. Can you define predicates like 'left_of(pos_1, pos_2)', right_of, forward, backward? That could get you going